# How do you capture Console I/O (not stdio) in Windows?

Tags: winapi, win32-process

Why would I want to?  Because I'm writing my own cmd.exe replacement!  I can CreateProcess and pass in handles to pipes for stdin and stdout and stderr, and I see how I can AllocConsole, FreeConsole, and AttachConsole, but how do I tell child programs that my program **is** the console?

More detail for clarification: I've got a window that can display text and accept input. I display the text "C:>" for instance.  The user types "foo.exe".  I locate foo.exe on the path, and call CreateProcess on it.  If it writes to stdout, I display that text on the screen.  If it reads from stdin, I pass in whatever keystrokes the user has pressed.  When the process terminates, I print the prompt again.  So far, so good.  It all works.  But then I try foo2.exe, which does a CreateFile on CONOUT$, which fails because there is no console attached to the process.  What does cmd.exe do to make it's children see it as a console?

Comment: "Because I'm writing my own cmd.exe replacement!" wow...may god have mercy on your soul xD

Comment: Everyone needs to do something outside their comfort zone once in a while :)

Comment: See the following link for insight into the difficulty level. http://jpsoft.com/blogs/2011/10/windows-command-line-tabbed-windows-and-jp-software-part-iv/

Answer (score 0):

This what you're after? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682079%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Your request is kinda vague, although I guess that's why you haven't already got what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it actually possible to create a full console replacement without injecting into the child process and hooking the console api's and WriteFile.

A cmd.exe replacement on the other hand should be possible, just make sure you actually created a console program and you should get a console and CreateProcess should make sure the child process gets the same console without messing with the i/o handles.